# Unresolvable merge conflicts following moving files

Tags: git, merge, rebase, mv

A colleague of mine made some major file changes without checking open branches that were under review, in total almost 1000 files were moved and half of those were touched in one PR while about 10% of the other half were touched in the other PR. Of course, major merge conflicts ensued when he merged to master.

However, everytime I try to rebase from aster to resolve the conflicts, the conflicts remain present in GitHub so I cannot merge. Both PR's contain an immense amount of work, so my blood pressure is up quite a bit in fear of having to redo stuff.

Has anyone encountered these seemingly unresolvable conflicts?

1. git checkout master
2. git pull
3. git fetch -p -t
4. git checkout
5. accept all current for all changes
6. git add .
7. commit & continue

After doing this (multiple times, also following git merge master instead of git rebase) the conflicts remain however. What's weird is that the path names are all correct in the new format.

Comment: [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) could possibly help depending on the merge conflicts. Anyways, you'd probably have the conflicts on everything that's branched off from master before the PR and is merged after the big PR was merged. Make sure new branches are up-to-date.

Comment: For changes that likely result in a lot of merge conflicts (like moving many files), it's sometimes best to get the repository to a somewhat clean state (with only few work-on-progress branches)

Comment: Sounds like you won't be the only one affected by the huge refactoring. Perhaps it's time to force-rewind the published history before the pain point and ask the smart collaborator to do their work again, this time in bite-sized chunks to reduce the pain of everyone else?

Comment: I spent the afternoon just copy pasting the files manually for one PR onto master directly. The big one still remains, unfortunately git rerere is not working for me.

Comment: You might get less/smaller conflicts by using [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) which will process commits one by one in sequence.

Comment: I tried it again with git merge, unfortunately no success